# # of key locks while updating

Tags: sql-server-2008, locking, primary-key

I am using SQL Server 2008, RTM. I have a simple table defined as

> create table t(id integer not null primary key)

This table has 50,000 records, just in case. When I issue an update transaction like

> begin transaction
>
> Update t
>
> set id=50001
>
> where id=5;

with no commit/rollback, it shows me one row affected. When I take a look at the result of the sp_locks, I and see there are two X locks on the KEY type granted, the Resource values for them are different from each other, the spid is the same.
Why there are two X locks on the key while there is only one row updated? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Because you're taking one key value, and assigning it another key value.

It's 2017, so I'm not going to use sp_lock. I'm going to use [sp_WhoIsActive](http://whoisactive.com/).

If we run it like this: `EXEC sp_WhoIsActive @get_locks = 1` we can get lock information.

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT dbo.t ( id )
SELECT TOP 50000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@DBTS)
FROM (SELECT 1 AS n FROM sys.messages AS m CROSS JOIN sys.messages AS m2) AS x
```

If we update one key value:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE t
SET    id = 50001
WHERE  id = 5;

ROLLBACK
```

The lock information looks like this:

```
<Object name="t" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="KEY" index_name="PK__t__3213E83FE76849A4" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="2" />
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
        <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK__t__3213E83FE76849A4" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="2" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
```

Two key locks! One key lock to get the key value we're modifying, and one lock to reserve the key value we're modifying it to.

If we modify two values...

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE t
SET    id += 50001
WHERE  id IN (5, 10)

ROLLBACK
```

We end up with four key locks. This pattern will continue if we do 3 or 4. There will be two key locks for each ID touched.

```
<Object name="t" schema_name="dbo">
  <Locks>
    <Lock resource_type="KEY" index_name="PK__t__3213E83FE76849A4" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="4" />
    <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
    <Lock resource_type="PAGE" page_type="*" index_name="PK__t__3213E83FE76849A4" request_mode="IX" request_status="GRANT" request_count="2" />
  </Locks>
```

Hitting three values:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE t
SET    id += 50001
WHERE  id IN (5, 10, 15)

ROLLBACK
```

Hitting four values:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE t
SET    id += 50001
WHERE  id IN (5, 10, 15, 20)

ROLLBACK
```

At least up until we modify *everything*.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE t
SET    id += 1

ROLLBACK
```

Then the lock type changes!

```
   <Object name="t" schema_name="dbo">
      <Locks>
        <Lock resource_type="ALLOCATION_UNIT.BULK_OPERATION_PAGE" index_name="PK__t__3213E83FE76849A4" request_mode="S" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
        <Lock resource_type="OBJECT" request_mode="X" request_status="GRANT" request_count="1" />
      </Locks>
    </Object>
```

This is due to the magic of the [split, sort, and collapse operations](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185551/unique-index-updates-and-statistics-row-modification-counters), which you can see in the [query plan here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bkvc4qEbf).

Hope this helps!